# ¿Cómo crear un spread operator con javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Se puede simular una prte del spread operator de la siguiente manera:

```
function Spread() {

    var spreadArgs = [];
    var length = arguments.length;
    var currentArg;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        currentArg = arguments[i];

        if (Array.isArray(currentArg)) {
            spreadArgs = spreadArgs.concat(currentArg);
        } else {
            spreadArgs.push(currentArg);
        }
    }
    return spreadArgs;
}

Spread('uno',[1,2], [3,4], 5,'dos') // retorna ["uno", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "dos"]
```

Pero lo que necesito es poder utilizar una de las ventajas más grandes que tiene, que haga referencia a cada elemento. Es como que en vez de hacer un retorno de un Array haga un retorno de cada elemento.
Por ejemplo necesitaría poder hacer:

```
Math.max(Spread(1,2,[4,2])) // pero ahora retorna NaN claro
```

es porque retorna un array y estaría haciendo

```
Math.max([1,2,4,2]) // NaN
```

sin embargo con

```
Math.max(...[1,2,4,2]) // 4
```

Me gustaría poder hacer este comportamiento con JS puro o algún polyfill estaría bien.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué quieres decir con *Javascript puro*? El operador spread existe en javascript desde hace tiempo en Javascript, que es tu último ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejemplo anterior una manera fácil de solucionarlo seria

```
Math.max.apply(Math, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Pero hay escenarios en lo que con apply no va a ser posible, es por eso que seria bueno tener una función que simule el Spread Operator para poder utilizarlo en ES5.

Comment: Creo que esto debería ser parte de la pregunta, no  una respuesta. Y estaría bien mostrar un escenario en el que esta solución no es aplicable